# Which UI toolkit are you using today with Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frameworks, aurelia, toolkit

We are currently evaluating Aurelia to use in new application. It seems to be, at least for me, some kind of problem to select UI toolkit, which to use? aurelix-ux looks quite basic and not updated recently. Any recommendation for UI?

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion based, because everyone that has their own framework is going to suggest their own framework for obvious reasons. On the other hand, you did not specify minimum requirements for the framework to support, so any framework will do. I suggest you make a list of features/components that you'll need, including other things that you deem important. This way you can check it against known frameworks and if they all meet the requirements, just pick one (it meets all your requirements so one isn't better than the other one).

Comment: yeps, it is opinion. It would be nice to know, what we should have on list and to evaluate.

Comment: Since you are asking for opinions, this is not proper a question for SO. Please ask on Aurelia Discourse: https://discourse.aurelia.io